# Analyse runtime errors in kivy

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, kivy

I just start my first kivy project. I wonder how to debug this kind of stuff. Even though I debugged deeply into the kivy code, I got no idea which kind of attribute is wrong or missing. So I am not only asking for a solution of this question, but also for ideas for effective analysis of the problem.
Here is the python and kivy-lang code together with the runtime logging.

Python:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MenuLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class HomeToucherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HomeToucherApp().run()
```

KV-Lang:

```
<MainLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 10
    Button:
        text: "Screen"
        size_hint: 1, 1
    MenuLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            text: "Edit"
        Button:
            text: "Setup"
```

Log:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/XXXXXXXX/ownCloud/Dev/exp/Lern1/main.py -m inspector
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\.kivy\logs\kivy_15-04-02_63.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_gif (img_pil ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.loader> with limit=500, timeout=60s
[INFO              ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.label> with limit=None, timeout=60.0s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.width> with limit=None, timeout=60.0s
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <C:/Users/XXXXXXXX/ownCloud/Dev/exp/Lern1\hometoucher.kv>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/XXXXXXXX/ownCloud/Dev/exp/Lern1/main.py", line 20, in <module>
     HomeToucherApp().run()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 765, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 585, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1444, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1521, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 118, in __getattr__
     raise AttributeError
 AttributeError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem. Can you run other kivy programs (e.g. the examples)?

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot of examples. Every thing works perfect. It is (almost) certainly my fault.

Comment: Your question inspired me to make an additional test. I made my first tests on a win8 laptop. Now i had a try on my linux box. Using py2.7 you a right. Every thing is okay.  Using py3.4, as on my laptop, it fails, too. So it might be a bug.

Comment: Ah, failing with python3 is interesting, I only tried 2.7. I'll try to reproduce that tomorrow.

Comment: Just a small bit of additional information. I run the program on win8 with py2.7: Program starts correctly, but window could not be resized.

Answer (score 0):

I just get a black screen unless I move the instance from Python to kv:

1. In hometoucher.kv (must be named that in lowercase to be detected) change `<MainLayout>` to `MainLayout`
2. In HomeToucherApp.py delete the build method and change it to pass (the kv file is automatically loaded).

Also, I don't have the error. Before, it said no listeners were declared, probably since if you instantiate MainLayout in the Python code, you are getting the blank one not the one in the KV file (since you redefine build instead of the default one loading the kv file with the name matching the class). I tried several other ways but that was the only solution for me on Kivy 2.1.0.